# The Freedman Dichotomies

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

**Definition**: A categorical dichotomy is said to be a “*Freedman Dichotomy*” if the sole evidence for its non-vacuity is the Disk Theorem (Theorem 1.1 of (F82)). This claims that a Casson handle is homeomorphic to a standard 2-handle (rather than just homotopic to a standard 2-handle, as originally proven by Casson (C86)).

**Question**: What are all of the known Freedman Dichotomies?

Let me illustrate by presenting examples I have found.

**Definition**: A smooth manifold is called “*exotic*” if it is homeomorphic to some standard smooth manifold, but not diffeomorphic to it. Examples of exotic spheres in dimension 7 and above were famously constructed by Milnor in 1959 (M59).

No examples of exotic manifolds of lower dimension are known, other than in dimension 4, where examples arise due to Freedman’s work.

**Answer 1**: 4-manifold exoticness is a Freedman Dichotomy.

In [a previous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87674/independent-evidence-for-the-classification-of-topological-4-manifolds/106894#106894) I sought, without success, to find any evidence for the Disk Theorem other than that contained in (F82).  [A follow-up MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108631/fake-versus-exotic/164434#164434) sought to quarantine the implications of the Disk Theorem with regard to exotic 4-manifolds. The result of these questions is that, without the Disk Theorem there would be no evidence for exoticness in 4 dimensions.

In fact, this can be improved:

**Answer 2**: The distinction between “small” and “large” exotic 4-manifolds is also a Freedman (sub)Dichotomy.

Small exotic structures arise from the contradiction between the Disk Theorem and the smooth h-cobordism theorem, while large exotic arise from the contradiction between the Disk Theorem and smooth connected-sum-splitting. A good overview of this is contained in (Sc05).

Moving on, we have the following.

**Definition**: A knot in the 3-sphere (the boundary of a 4-ball) is “*smoothly slice*” if it bounds a proper smoothly embedded disk in the 4-ball. A knot is “*topologically slice*” if it bounds a proper continuously embedded disk $D$ which can be extended to a continuous embedding of $D\times D$ into a normal neighbourhood of the disk.

**Answer 3**: The distinction between topological sliceness and smooth sliceness for knots in dimension 3 is a Freedman Dichotomy.

The reason is that the existence of a topological slice disk for knots with Alexander polynomial equal to 1 follows solely from the Disk Theorem, while the non-existence of smooth slice disks comes from smooth knot theory – often allied to gauge theory or smooth invariants of knots.

The E8 lattice is a symmetric $8\times 8$ matrix of integers that appears in the study of Lie groups. As it is unimodular, the question arises as to whether E8 is the intersection form of a closed simply connected 4-manifold (which must be unimodular).

Since the E8 lattice has signature 8, a theorem of Rohlin says that it cannot be the intersection form of a smooth closed simply connected 4-manifold (which must have signature divisible by 16).

**Answer 4**: The existence/non-existence of a (non-smooth) topological 4-manifold with E8 intersection form is a Freedman Dichotomy.

Such a 4-manifold exists by the classification of topological 4-manifolds, which once again, follows from the Disk Theorem.

**Definition**: A “*triangulation*” of a topological manifold is a homeomorphism to a locally finite simplicial complex.

Topological manifolds of dimension greater than 4 which do not admit a triangulation have been known for decades (KS77).

**Answer 5**: The triangulability/non-triangulability of 4-manifolds is a Freedman Dichotomy.

Unpublished work of Casson relates his invariant to the triangulability or otherwise of topological 4-manifolds, whose existence is guaranteed by their classification - see the exposition (AMcC14).

So what other Freedman Dichotomies exist? And, of course, any corrections or comments on the above five examples are welcome.

(AMcC14) Akbulut, Selman, and John D. McCarthy. Casson's Invariant for Oriented Homology Three-Spheres: An Exposition.(MN-36). Princeton University Press, 2014.

(C86) Casson, A. J. (1986), "Three lectures on new infinite constructions in 4-dimensional manifolds", A la recherche de la topologie perdue, Progr. Math., 62, Boston, MA: Birkhauser Boston, 201-244.

(F82) Freedman, Michael Hartley. "The topology of four-dimensional manifolds." J. Differential Geom 17.3 (1982): 357-453.

(KS77) Kirby, Robion C., and Laurence Siebenmann. Foundational essays on topological manifolds, smoothings, and triangulations. No. 88. Princeton University Press, 1977.

(M59) Milnor, John. "Differentiable structures on spheres." American Journal of Mathematics 81.4 (1959): 962-972.

(Sc05) Scorpan, Alexandru. The wild world of 4-manifolds. American Mathematical Soc., 2005.

Comment: It would help if you defined your terminology.

Comment: Further definitions and references have now been added.

Comment: What is a "categorical dichotomy"? What does it mean for a dichotomy to be "non-vacuous"? (Dichotomy can mean many things including "binary alternative", "division", and "contrast.") It seems like you are just talking about certain mathematical phenomena and you want to know those phenomena whose only known proof relies on Freedman's Disk Theorem.

Comment: For dichotomy I guess "division into two mutually exclusive, opposed, or contradictory groups" is closest to what I mean. A dichotomy is "vacuous" if one of the mutually exclusive groups is the empty set. I was trying to be more precise than simply referring to "mathematical phenomena", but your last sentence is mostly correct.

Comment: So then the dichotomy of "4-manifold exoticness" would mean what? A division into non-exotic and exotic manifolds?

Comment: Yes - that summarizes the conclusion of the previous (linked) MO questions.

Comment: Have you looked at Kirby's book "The topology of 4-manifolds"? It contains a summary of Freedman's proof, although it does refer back to his paper for complete details. It might also contain more Freedman dichotomies. (I don't have the book in front of me. Just going by memory and a review I found online.)

Comment: The book certainly contains discusions of some of the above. In particular Chapters 7 and 8 relate to Answers 1 and 2, while Chapter 11section 7 relates to Answer 3. Other than that, I'm not sure. Of course, the book was not peer-reviewed and has been the subject of corrections  Stong, Richard. "Uniqueness of π1-negligible embeddings in 4-manifolds: a correction to theorem 10.5 of Freedman and Quinn." Topology 32.4(1993):677-699.
Teichner, Peter. "On the star-construction for topological 4-manifolds." Geometric Topology (1996): 300-312.

Comment: Generally speaking I think there's value in pointing out major results in mathematics that have no alternative proof at present than one that might be deemed long and complicated.  There's quite a few results like that in mathematics, and even topology.  Freedman's work is remarkable in that there's such a rich texture of consequences.  Most other results of this kind (where there is no alternative proof) seem to have more limited consequences, at present.

Comment: @BrendanGuilfoyle: I was referring to Kirby's book, not Freedman-Quinn.

Comment: @BrendanGuilfoyle: I'm also a little puzzled by your comment. The stated intent of this question was to find dichotomies that are implied by Freedman's result, whereas, judging by your comment, the actual intent may actually be to cast doubt on the correctness of Freedman's result.

Comment: @JimConant: I'm not so worried as to the truth of Freedman's Fields-medal work.  I haven't verified everything in his work.  I don't know to what extent his work has been vetted.  But I think it's fine for people to be curious about it and to explore those issues.  In the end, his work is generally accepted.  At some point the literature will be enriched with either a new proof of his work or (crazier things have happened) a counter-example to something in it.   I don't think it hurts mathematics for there to be people trying to actively dis-prove his work, or anyone else's work. . .

Comment: I'd be honoured if there were a group of people trying to dis-prove some of my results.

Comment: Oh, the Kirby book. That does indeed contain a good summary of the Disk Theorem, but doesn’t have any other Freedman dichotomies that I can see. The intent of this question is precisely as stated: to identify dichotomies that would not exist were it not for the Disk Theorem - a part of the critical exploration of this result. Feel free to make whatever judgements you like, but I’m primarily interested in the answers to the questions.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Sure, I have no problem with the question. I have always wanted to understand Freedman's proof in detail myself, but have never found the time to devote to it. I do know that there was initial resistance to Freedman's proof, but in the end it was heavily vetted and accepted. So far the only evidence I've heard to suggest it might be wrong is: 1) Counterintuitive implications. 2) No independent or simpler proof. 
For me and many others, the counterintuitive implications are a feature, not a bug! While it would be nice to have a simpler proof, the fact that no-one has found (ctd)

Comment: is pretty thin evidence that the original proof is wrong. Still, I, and many others, would love to see a simpler proof.

Comment: The truth or otherwise of the Disk Theorem is not the subject of this question, but if that’s what interests you, look at

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voH5m6HDRVE

from 53m 23s on. Clearly even the published proof requires further work. However, rather than get dragged into that, I am attempting in these question to come at the issue from a different direction.

Comment: @BrendanGuilfoyle: please tag me when you are responding. I only have been seeing your responses because I happen to look back at the question. Otherwise, the system doesn't notify me. Anyway, I was there at Freedman's 60th, at that very talk. I remember Mike saying that he felt some sympathy for Perelman since his work was being held to a higher standard.

Comment: @RyanBudney The classification of finite simple groups is one of the longest long proofs in mathematics and also has one of the richest sets of consequences.

Comment: This is an old question, but I thought I would update it to include a reference to the recently published book containing a proof of the Disk Embedding Theorem, bringing together the work of many mathematicians. https://www.amazon.com/Disc-Embedding-Theorem-Michael-Freedman-ebook/dp/B097YSVL1R It contains a nice chart showing the dependencies of various 4-manifold results.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather make this a comment, since I am only suggesting a hitherto apparently not well known dichotomy in the literature, not in mathematics, but it won't allow me to post comments.  Anyway.

Here
https://eudml.org/doc/109989
is an account by Siebenmann of Freedman's Casson handle proof. It contains a detailed construction of the partial parametrisation of a Casson handle that Freedman called the design, and another exposition of the sphere to sphere theorem.  Mitosis is not proven there, but this was independently described by Gompf and Singh (see Durham conference proceedings 1984).

Also, with regards to recent discussion above, Jim Conant was talking about Kirby's "Topology of 4-manifolds" book, not the Freedman-Quinn book of the same name, because Kirby also sketched Freedman's proof in his book.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was aware of the Bourbaki paper, but my French wasn't quite up to job of dissecting it. As you say, it's more a literature dichotomy than a mathematical one, but worth pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

One of Freedman's results is that a homology $3$-sphere admits a tame topological embedding into $\mathbb R^4$.   So here is an odd fact:

Let $M$ be the Poincare dodecahedral space.  There is an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$ homeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb R$.  But there is no open subset of $\mathbb R^4$ diffeomorphic to $M \times \mathbb R$.

The obstruction to the smooth embedding of $M$ comes from the Rochlin invariant of the smooth $4$ manifold $M$ bounds in $\mathbb R^4$.

One additional twist to this is that $M \setminus \{*\}$, i.e. the once-punctured Poincare Dodecahedral Space admits a beautiful smooth embedding in $\mathbb R^4$.  The problem with this embedding with respect to the above is that the sphere surrounding the puncture point is knotted, i.e. the punctured Poincare dodecahedral space is a Seifert Surface for a non-trivially embedded $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^4$.  So there's no clear way of how to modify this embedding to get an embedded $M$.

These embeddings of Freedman's use the standardness of Casson 2-handles.  I have not seen a construction of any such embedding by any other means.

edit: I suppose one reason the above could be deemed hard to accept is you would think you could `smooth' a topological embedding $M \to \mathbb R^4$.  Smooth maps are dense, so every topological embedding can be approximated by a smooth map, but that smooth map (I presume) would have degeneracies.  I think it would be useful to complete this picture to describe the degeneracies of such smooth approximations, in some combinatorial language.